# ssh No route to host after quitting terminal

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

I was installing a package on a test/staging server.
After a while it just halted so I couldn't `ctrl-c ctrl-d` or anything so I just quit the terminal.

Now, when I try to ssh again, I get 
`ssh: connect to host 193.xx.xx.xx port 22: No route to host`

Cannot run any of the jenkins tasks (restart web server, redeploy) because the first thing any task does it trying to ssh into the server.

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

Your staging server may crashed. 
Try to reboot and check syslogs

Comment: well I can't reboot it, because I'd have to access it via ssh, which is not working..

Comment: If that would be the case try to check if its ssh port is accessible. There are lot of webbased network tool to check if ssh port is open. Maybe your staging server runs out of internet connection.

Comment: yes, the port is not accessible. the nc -zv 193.xx.xx.xx.xx &> /dev/null; echo $? outputs 1

Comment: "No route to host" implies some kind of network outage. If the target server was down, the OP would get a different error message.